# How can we define optical isomerism?What is the example of non enatiomeric optical isomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry

My book has very vaguely explained these concepts,I can't understand anything from there.

Through a little bit of research on the internet I came to following conclusion:

1. that optical isomers are either dextrorotatory or levorotatory
2. all enantiomers are either dextro or levo so they are optical isomers.
3. Some diastereomers may also be related as d- or l- (though I feel the angle of rotation will be different) and thus can be optical isomers.

I feel I am missing something or have the wrong concept entirely.

These are pics from my book.
In the heading of optical isomers there are 4 isomers of tartaric acid mentioned,why is that?So how many types of optical isomers are there?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your book is pretty bad, I'm afraid to say. The most helpful thing for you would probably be for you to find a better book. But in the meantime, it would be better if you could (a) say which book it is, and (b) don't post screenshots, but rather quote the relevant paragraphs of text. You can [edit] your post to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

There are, in the sense you are asking the question, three types of optical isomers: +, -, and optically inactive. This is detailed in pages of the textbook you have uploaded.

You should think about optical isomers in how they are determined. Imagine you have a machine which we will call and "optical isometer". To use this machine, you put in any compound in solution, and it will tell you one of three outputs:

1. "This compound polarises light in the clockwise direction"
2. "This compound polarises light in the anti-clockwise direction"
3. "This compound does not polarise light"

Now, our optical isometer doesn't know any chemistry, but it does know how to tell if light is being polarised by our compound in solution. If you fundamentally think of isomers as identical in their molecular formula, but differing in their spatial arrangement of atoms, you need only imagine as **optical isomers being different in how the spatial arrangement of atoms polarises light.**

Let's imagine we have a solution of a tartaric acid, but we don't know what isomeric form it is in. The options are:

1. meso-tartaric acid
2. (+)tartaric acid
3. (-)tartaric acid
4. A mixture of (+) and (-)tartaric acid.

Where I think you have been confused by the textbook is that option number 4 doesn't actually describe different spatial arrangements of tartaric acid, rather it describes a mixture of options 2 and 3. So when it says there are four isomeric forms, it isn't strictly correct about that.

Now, how will we determine what isomer of tartaric acid we have in solution? One thing that we can do to find this out would be to use our optical isometer. We put our solution in and it outputs: "This compound polarises light in the clockwise direction". We know that of our four possible options, only (+)tartaric acid polarises light in the clockwise direction. Likewise, we would know it to be (-)tartaric acid if the light were polarised in the anti-clockwise direction.

What if our optical isometer output, "This compound does not polarise light"? Then this means that our compound is optically inactive. We know that both the meso- form and the racemic (mixture of (+) and (-)) don't polarise light in either the clockwise or anti-clockwise direction, and so we would need further analysis to find out for sure!

There are other types of light polarisation, but not in the sense this book is talking about optical isomers. This textbook seems to be a little confusing, but these ideas are actually really well explained on places like wikipedia or khan academy, so next time you get stuck, don't worry too much about the textbook but give other resources a shot!

Hope this helped,

Edan

Answer (score 0):

You're starting backwards here.

The first term to start with is *chiral*. A chiral object is non-superimposable on its mirror image.

A chiral molecule has two enantiomers--the two optically active mirror images. The optical rotation is opposite (levo versus dextro) for each of the pair.

Diastereomers are structures that have the same connectivity but are not enantiomers. These most commonly result from a molecule having multiple stereocenters, where we can identify pairs of such molecules with the same connectivity but the sense of chirality in the stereocenters are not all the same nor all different.

In the case of tartaric acid, there is a chiral form. The chiral form has two enantiomeric isomers that have opposite optical rotation. Then, there is a third isomer that is diastereomeric to the other two. Due the level of symmetry (and this will be hard to explain without going into more detail), there is no separate fourth isomer.

Comment: hmm..but I still dont know how to define optical isomerism.and why diastereomers are written in the heading of optical isomers?

Comment: Diastereoisomers ARE a type of optical isomer. An optical isomer, more generally known as a steteoisomer, or spatial isomer differs from other spatial isomers only in the spatial disposition of its atoms. Changes in composition and connectivity is not allowed between steteoisomers.